# Jquery DataTables change order to desc when it sorts

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using DataTables to display some data and it works great but I want to customize it slightly and not sure how.

What I want to do is when a user clicks on a column heading to sort that column I want it to initially order descendingly rather than ascendingly. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Both versions 1.9 and 1.10 have similar ways of handing this; see SteD's answer for 1.9 (here's the [asSorting 1.9 documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns))  and my answer below for 1.10's default descending sort for 1 or more (or `_all`!) columns.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at this: [DataTables sorting direction control example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/sorting_control.html)

You can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] }, //first sort desc, then asc
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks works great!  Do you know any way that when sorting you can have blank/ empty fields appear last rather than first?

Comment: Thanks for this.  Do you happen to know if a way has been added to set the default for the entire table?  I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work with v. 1.10.x now? Can't find an appropriate solution.

Comment: @ConAntonakos, see my answer for the 1.10 solution

Comment: @Dave, you can target `_all` columns in version 1.10 with my solution. You also might be able to use `_all` as the target in 1.9, too [as seen here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns). See the asSorting example using aoColumnDefs to specify `"desc","asc"` and target `_all`

Answer (score 6):

The current version of DataTables (1.10) provides the following way of switching this default sorting order with the property `orderSequence` under `columnDefs` (or `columns` but less flexible).

Here's the documentation on [`orderSequence`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderSequence).

```
"columnDefs": [
    { "orderSequence": [ "desc", "asc"], "targets": [ 1 ] },
]
```

As it also mentions, you may force a column to *only* sort when clicked as DESC or ASC which your interface may very well benefit from.

In my case, I needed to have columns descending their sort on initial click for an indeterminate number of columns so I decided to switch the example to target a column header's `class` name rather than explicitly defining each column as `"targets":[1],"targets":[2],...[n]` or programatically building an array of the indices of columns I cared about.

You can target columns multiple ways [according to here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets).

The end result is a table definition like so:

```
<table><thead><tr>
    <th class='descendFirst'>DESCend when first clicked</th>
    <th>a normally sorted ASC->DESC->... column</th>
    ...
</tr></thead></table>
```

And Data Table empowered as such:

```
$("#table").dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {"orderSequence": ["desc","asc"], "targets":"descendFirst" },
    ]
});
```

Voila! First click descending sort on all columns with a `<th>` marked with a class of 'descendFirst' (an arbitrarily chosen, descriptive class name).

Answer (score 2):

In response to sorting blanks last, here's what I came up with--
(I just HATE blanks sorting first!!)

*Include these custom sort functions*

```
// custom sort functions
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['text-blankslast-asc'] = function (x, y) {  
   x = (x == "") ? String.fromCharCode(255) : x;  
   y = (y == "") ? String.fromCharCode(255) : y;  
   return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));  
};  

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['text-blankslast-desc'] = function (x, y) {  
   x = (x == "") ? String.fromCharCode(0) : x;  
   y = (y == "") ? String.fromCharCode(0) : y;  
   return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));  
};
```

*Apply the sort tags to the appropriate columns*

```
// init example  
$('#table2').dataTable({  
   "bJQueryUI": true,  
   "aoColumns": [  
      null,  
      { "sType": "text-blankslast" },  
      { "sType": "text-blankslast" },  
      { "sType": "text-blankslast" },  
      null  
   ]  
});
```

Comment: or just add hidden text to have it show up in the appropriate place.  Ex. <div style="visibility:hidden;opacity:0;">zzzzz</div> - a hack, but easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else like Dave and myself is looking for a way to set the sort order on all columns, the following may work for you. In order to change the sorting order on all of the columns I set up a loop to alter the settings after the table had instantiated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var example_table = $('#example').dataTable();
    $.each(example_table.dataTableSettings[0].aoColumns, function(key, column) {
        column.asSorting = [ "desc", "asc" ];
    } );
} );
```

Hope that helps. Tested on jQuery 1.11.0 and DataTables 1.10.0

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get your blank ones last would be a bit of a hack (since the sort is working correctly).

Instead of returning blank values from your server, return something like: "[Blank]"

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure square brackets will come after alphanumeric codes.  Also square brackets traditionally symbolises something that hasn't been completed or confirmed yet.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
       settings = {
           aoColumnDefs: [
            {
                orderSequence: ["desc", "asc"],
                aTargets: ['_all']
            }
        ]};

        $('.dataTable').DataTable(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is to set default sorting order desc first then asceding for all columns.

```
aoColumnDefs: [{
    orderSequence: ["desc", "asc"],
    aTargets: ['_all']
}],
```