# Sorting datatables by descending order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using datatables (JQuery plugin) to sort data form a simple html markup table.

Pardon my lack of javascript know-how but can someone edit this code to make the first column sort the data by descending order?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#concise').dataTable( {  "pageLength": 40} );
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "...e.g..London");
$("aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
} );
</script>
```

I thought that the last line would work but it doesn't...

The data needs to be so that the first column sorts ALL the data by numeric values in a descending order, i.e. high to low.

All feedback hugely appreciated - thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725321/jquery-datatables-change-order-to-desc-when-it-sorts

Answer (score 2):

This solved it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    // Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
    oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise `Table Id Name`

```
 $('#concise').DataTable({
    order:"desc"
 });
```